# How to remount all databrick clusters' Azure ADLS mount points?

Tags: pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks, mount

Due to the reason of my account service principle secret expired (concept: https://www.thedataswamp.com/blog/databricks-connect-to-azure-sql-with-service-principal), I need to remount all mount points with new service principle secret across all clusters.

First I have 3 clusters, clusterA , clusterB & clusterC;
And I have 3 containers (as mount points), /mnt/001disk, /mnt/002disk, /mnt/003disk that all clusters mounting them.

So now I need to remount all mount points with below scripts:

```
storage_account_name = "aaaaaaaaaa"
tenant = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
service_principal_id = "yyyyyy"
service_principal_secret = "zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz"

def func_mount_adls(source:str, mount_point:str):
  print(source)
  print(mount_point)
  # declare necessary information for ADLS connection
  configs = {
    'fs.azure.account.auth.type': 'OAuth',
    'fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type': 'org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider',
    'fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id': service_principal_id,
    'fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret': service_principal_secret,
    'fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint': f'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/token'
  }
  mount_points = list(map(lambda mount: mount.mountPoint, dbutils.fs.mounts()))    
  # mount storage if not mounted yet
  if not (mount_point in mount_points):
    dbutils.fs.mount(
      source = source,
      mount_point = mount_point,
      extra_configs = configs
    )

# Databricks notebook source
import os
import re
import time
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

storage_account_name = os.environ['storage_account_name']

# COMMAND ---------
listToReMnt = [
  "001disk",
  "002disk",
  "003disk"
]

def unmount_container(container_name):
  print(f"unmount /mnt/{container_name}")
  dbutils.fs.unmount(f"/mnt/{container_name}")

def mount_contianer(container_name):
  return_value = {}
  container_name = container_name
  
  source = f'abfss://{container_name}@{storage_account_name}.dfs.core.windows.net/'
  mount_point = f'/mnt/{container_name}'

  mount_points = list(map(lambda mount: mount.mountPoint, dbutils.fs.mounts()))
  
  print(f"mount /mnt/{container_name}")
  print(mount_points)

  # mount storage if not mounted yet
  if not (mount_point in mount_points):
    try:
      func_mount_adls(source=source, mount_point=mount_point)
    except Exception as e:
    print(e)
  
for x in listToReMnt:
  print("==============================================================")
  unmount_container(x)
  mount_contianer(x)
  print('dbutils.fs.ls(f"/mnt/{x}")')
  print(dbutils.fs.ls(f"/mnt/{x}"))
```

So here is my question, do I need to run the remount script in each cluster? Or after I run in 1 cluster, else will be updated accordingly? If so, how to ensure cluster security (e.g. system to access or AD to access)

Base on the documentation https://docs.databricks.com/dbfs/mounts.html, it mentioned that

```
When you create a mount point through a cluster, cluster users can immediately access the mount point. To use the mount point in another running cluster, you must run dbutils.fs.refreshMounts() on that running cluster to make the newly created mount point available for use.
```

Do this mean when I update 1 cluster (e.g. clusterA) , else will be automatically updated (e.g. clusterB & clusterC)?

If no, do this mean i need to remount those containers in every cluster manual? (seems bit stupid)

Note that terraform/similar tool are not considered due to requirement & limitation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- As stated in [this same document](https://docs.databricks.com/dbfs/mounts.html#unmount-a-mount-point) (in the warning section), the `refreshMounts()` helps in applying the changes made to a mount point across all clusters.
- Therefore, you can try using `refreshMounts()` in all the clusters respectively.
- However, remounting in all the clusters would also work (in case). But instead of doing it manually by changing the clusters in the notebook code each time, you can use workflows (even to run refresh mounts on all clusters).
- Navigate to workflows and create a Job. There add 3 tasks that execute one after another with same remount code but with different clusters, which you can select while creating a task.

[image]

- So, whenever you need to make modifications to your mount points, you can simply execute this job, or even schedule it to same period as the expiration date of the secrets of service principal thus automating the process.

Comment: how about security concern? [1] currently i remount in clusterA (with ServiceP) , and seems i can access ADLS in clusterB(with same ServiceP) without remount process in cluster B.  

[2] Also, in clusterC (using AD & ACL to control the ADLS access), seems can read all the data in those mount point that i work on clusterA (without remount process in cluster C). [question] so how to explain above cases?

Comment: Even if you delete the service P, you will be able to access the data due to cached credential information. I have tried this and was able to access the mount anyway. If security is really a concern, you can try moving from mount to setting spark configuration for each cluster.